# Is there a way to use DataRepeater in Visual Studio without installing Microsoft PowerPacks?

Tags: c#, winforms

I used to use Datarepeater. But the 2013 one is different from the 2010 version.
I need a Datarepeater in my ToolBox. But I don't want download it. Because I am in a competition with no internet.

How do I do?

Comment: DataRepeater is part of the power pack, and it's a Windows Forms control. You can't use it with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

A repeater is a Web Forms control.

When creating your project, choose C# -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application.

Then choose Web Forms template.

Then, toolbox -> data -> Repeater

Comment: But I wanna use it in my Windows Form application.

Comment: Use the appropriate Winform control. DataGridView http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have to use the DataRepeater resources. Because I can repeat any control...images, etc... not only the data.

Comment: @user17245 You specified Web Forms when you tagged this question. Please update the tags accordingly if that is incorrect.

Comment: No, I don't specified Web Forms. I sepecified WinForms, but anyone changed it.